# Using SunPKCS11 security provider on Solaris SPARC 11.3 shoots up JVM CPU consumption

Tags: java, solaris, sparc

We have a Solaris SPARC system (Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC) running Apache Tomcat 8.0.41. On this system, we are observing very high CPU consumption under a small web server load. Specifically, running 10-15 concurrent HTTPS requests threads causes CPU consumption on this 64 vCPU machine to reach up to 80-90%.

However, when we change the security provider ordering in java.security file by moving the SunPKCS11 provider to the bottom of the list, CPU consumption goes significantly lower (below 5%) in the same scenarios.

We ran the similar tests on an older Solaris 10 SPARC system (Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 SPARC), there we do not see this problem even though the java.security settings as well as sunpkcs11-solaris.cfg files are same on both systems. Java version being used is also the same (1.8.0_131).

My questions:
1. Are there any known issues with 11.3 version of Solaris SPARC w.r.t. SunPKCS11 security provider?
2. Are there any workaround/solutions to this problem other than changing the security provider order in java.security file?

Here are some logs output using -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11 option:

```
SunPKCS11 loading /opt/java/jre/lib/security/sunpkcs11-solaris.cfg
Information for provider SunPKCS11-Solaris
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: 2.20
  manufacturerID: Oracle Corporation
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: Sun Crypto Softtoken
  libraryVersion: 1.01
All slots: 0
Slots with tokens: 0
Slot info for slot 0:
  slotDescription: Sun Metaslot
  manufacturerID: Oracle Corporation
  flags: CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
Token info for token in slot 0:
  label: Sun Metaslot
  manufacturerID: Oracle Corporation
  model: 1.0
  serialNumber:
  flags: CKF_RNG | CKF_DUAL_CRYPTO_OPERATIONS | CKF_TOKEN_INITIALIZED
  ulMaxSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxRwSessionCount: CK_EFFECTIVELY_INFINITE
  ulRwSessionCount: 0
  ulMaxPinLen: 256
  ulMinPinLen: 1
  ulTotalPublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePublicMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulTotalPrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  ulFreePrivateMemory: CK_UNAVAILABLE_INFORMATION
  hardwareVersion: 0.00
  firmwareVersion: 0.00
  utcTime:
```

Some of the configuration information:

```
# pkg info entire
             Name: entire
          Summary: entire incorporation including Support Repository Update (Oracle Solaris 11.3.13.4.0).
      Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same
                   build.  WARNING: Proper system update and correct package
                   selection depend on the presence of this incorporation.
                   Removing this package will result in an unsupported system.
                   For more information see:
                   https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=2045311.1
         Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
            State: Installed
        Publisher: solaris
          Version: 0.5.11 (Oracle Solaris 11.3.13.4.0)
    Build Release: 5.11
           Branch: 0.175.3.13.0.4.0
   Packaging Date: September 29, 2016 05:55:02 PM
Last Install Time: May 16, 2017 08:37:07 PM
             Size: 5.46 kB
             FMRI: pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.13.0.4.0:20160929T175502Z

# virtinfo
NAME            CLASS
logical-domain  current
non-global-zone supported
kernel-zone     supported
logical-domain  supported


# zonename
global
```

Cryptoadm output:

```
# cryptoadm list -vm


User-level providers:
=====================

Provider: /usr/lib/security/$ISA/pkcs11_kernel.so
/usr/lib/security/$ISA/pkcs11_kernel.so: no slots presented.

Provider: /usr/lib/security/$ISA/pkcs11_softtoken.so
Number of slots: 1

Slot #1
Description: Sun Crypto Softtoken                                            
Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation              
PKCS#11 Version: 2.20
Hardware Version: 0.0
Firmware Version: 0.0
Token Present: True
Slot Flags: CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT 
Token Label: Sun Software PKCS#11 softtoken  
Manufacturer ID: Oracle Corporation              
Model: 1.0             
Serial Number:                 
Hardware Version: 0.0
Firmware Version: 0.0
UTC Time:                 
PIN Min Length: 1
PIN Max Length: 256
Flags: CKF_RNG CKF_RESTORE_KEY_NOT_NEEDED CKF_DUAL_CRYPTO_OPERATIONS 
Mechanisms:
                                                     E D     S   V   P       E
                                                     n e D   i V e K a   U D C
                                                     c c i   g e r e i   n e  
                                                     r r g S + r + y r W w r C
                                                     y y e i R i R G G r r i a
                                                   H p p s g e f e e e a a v p
Mechanism Name                 Minimum    Maximum  W t t t n c y c n n p p e s
----------------------------- -------- ----------  - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
CKM_CAMELLIA_CBC                    16         32  . X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_CAMELLIA_CBC_PAD                16         32  . X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_CAMELLIA_ECB                    16         32  . X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_CAMELLIA_KEY_GEN                16         32  . . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_DES_CBC                          8          8  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_DES_CBC_PAD                      8          8  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_DES_ECB                          8          8  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_DES_KEY_GEN                      8          8  X . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_DES_MAC_GENERAL                  8          8  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_DES_MAC                          8          8  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_DES3_CBC                        16         24  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_DES3_CBC_PAD                    16         24  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_DES3_ECB                        16         24  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_DES2_KEY_GEN                    16         16  X . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_DES3_KEY_GEN                    24         24  X . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_AES_CBC                         16         32  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_AES_CBC_PAD                     16         32  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_AES_CTR                         16         32  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_AES_ECB                         16         32  X X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_AES_KEY_GEN                     16         32  X . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_BLOWFISH_CBC                     4         56  . X X . . . . . . . X X . .
CKM_BLOWFISH_KEY_GEN                 4         56  . . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_SHA_1                            0          0  X . . X . . . . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA_1_HMAC                       1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA_1_HMAC_GENERAL               1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA224                           0          0  X . . X . . . . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA224_HMAC                      1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA224_HMAC_GENERAL              1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA256                           0          0  X . . X . . . . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA256_HMAC                      1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA256_HMAC_GENERAL              1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA384                           0          0  X . . X . . . . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA384_HMAC                      1        128  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA384_HMAC_GENERAL              1        128  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA512                           0          0  X . . X . . . . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA512_HMAC                      1        128  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA512_HMAC_GENERAL              1        128  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SSL3_SHA1_MAC                    1        512  . . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_MD5                              0          0  X . . X . . . . . . . . . .
CKM_MD5_HMAC                         1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_MD5_HMAC_GENERAL                 1         64  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SSL3_MD5_MAC                     1        512  . . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_RC4                              8       2048  . X X . . . . . . . . . . .
CKM_RC4_KEY_GEN                      8       2048  . . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_DSA                            512       3072  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_DSA_SHA1                       512       1024  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_DSA_KEY_PAIR_GEN               512       3072  X . . . . . . . . X . . . .
CKM_RSA_PKCS                       256       8192  X X X . X X X X . . X X . .
CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN          256       8192  X . . . . . . . . X . . . .
CKM_RSA_X_509                      256       8192  X X X . X X X X . . X X . .
CKM_MD5_RSA_PKCS                   256       8192  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS                  256       8192  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA224_RSA_PKCS                256       8192  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS                256       8192  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA384_RSA_PKCS                256       8192  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_SHA512_RSA_PKCS                256       8192  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_DH_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN            64       8192  X . . . . . . . . X . . . .
CKM_DH_PKCS_DERIVE                  64       8192  X . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_MD5_KEY_DERIVATION               1         16  X . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_SHA1_KEY_DERIVATION              1         20  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_SHA224_KEY_DERIVATION            1         28  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_SHA256_KEY_DERIVATION            1         32  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_SHA384_KEY_DERIVATION            1         48  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_SHA512_KEY_DERIVATION            1         64  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_PBE_SHA1_RC4_128                 0          0  . . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2                      0          0  . . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_SSL3_PRE_MASTER_KEY_GEN         48         48  . . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_TLS_PRE_MASTER_KEY_GEN          48         48  . . . . . . . . X . . . . .
CKM_SSL3_MASTER_KEY_DERIVE          48         48  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_TLS_MASTER_KEY_DERIVE           48         48  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_SSL3_MASTER_KEY_DERIVE_DH       48         48  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_TLS_MASTER_KEY_DERIVE_DH        48         48  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_SSL3_KEY_AND_MAC_DERIVE          0          0  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_TLS_KEY_AND_MAC_DERIVE           0          0  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_TLS_PRF                          0          0  . . . . . . . . . . . . X .
CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN                112        571  X . . . . . . . . X . . . .
CKM_ECDSA                          112        571  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_ECDSA_SHA1                     112        571  X . . . X . X . . . . . . .
CKM_ECDH1_DERIVE                   112        571  X . . . . . . . . . . . X .

Provider: /usr/lib/security/$ISA/pkcs11_tpm.so
/usr/lib/security/$ISA/pkcs11_tpm.so: no slots presented.

Kernel providers:
=================
des: CKM_DES_ECB,CKM_DES_CBC,CKM_DES3_ECB,CKM_DES3_CBC
aes: CKM_AES_ECB,CKM_AES_CBC,CKM_AES_CTR,CKM_AES_CCM,CKM_AES_GCM,CKM_AES_GMAC,CKM_AES_CFB128,CKM_AES_XTS,CKM_AES_XCBC_MAC
arcfour: CKM_RC4
blowfish: CKM_BLOWFISH_ECB,CKM_BLOWFISH_CBC
camellia: CKM_CAMELLIA_ECB,CKM_CAMELLIA_CBC
ecc: CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN,CKM_ECDH1_DERIVE,CKM_ECDSA,CKM_ECDSA_SHA1
sha1: CKM_SHA_1,CKM_SHA_1_HMAC,CKM_SHA_1_HMAC_GENERAL
sha2: CKM_SHA224,CKM_SHA224_HMAC,CKM_SHA224_HMAC_GENERAL,CKM_SHA256,CKM_SHA256_HMAC,CKM_SHA256_HMAC_GENERAL,CKM_SHA384,CKM_SHA384_HMAC,CKM_SHA384_HMAC_GENERAL,CKM_SHA512,CKM_SHA512_HMAC,CKM_SHA512_HMAC_GENERAL,CKM_SHA512_160,CKM_SHA512_160_HMAC,CKM_SHA512_160_HMAC_GENERAL,CKM_SHA512_224,CKM_SHA512_224_HMAC,CKM_SHA512_224_HMAC_GENERAL,CKM_SHA512_256,CKM_SHA512_256_HMAC,CKM_SHA512_256_HMAC_GENERAL
md4: CKM_MD4
md5: CKM_MD5,CKM_MD5_HMAC,CKM_MD5_HMAC_GENERAL
rsa: CKM_RSA_PKCS,CKM_RSA_X_509,CKM_MD5_RSA_PKCS,CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS,CKM_SHA224_RSA_PKCS,CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS,CKM_SHA384_RSA_PKCS,CKM_SHA512_RSA_PKCS
swrand: No mechanisms presented.
n2rng/0: No mechanisms presented.
```

Comment: What exact hardware are the different instances running on?  SPARC servers can have hardware-accelerated cryptography, and the SunPKCS11 implementation can use that.  You can set `-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11` to get more information.  Also, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html

Comment: Thank you for the java switch, I've added initial part of the output that i got after enabling it. Is there presence or absence of some field in there that indicates if there is a hardware accelerator present or absent?